# For IE 8 how to change border colour of text/input field if data entered is invalid using angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I did tried http://plnkr.co/edit/A6gvyoXbBd2kfToPmiiA?p=preview but it is not working IE8. I need to change border colour of input field if data entered is not valid. and colour should get change after completion of data input(after pressing tab).

Comment: in just 26 more days..XP is [losing support](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/end-support-help), the OS for IE8. hopefully you can too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If feel your pain- we just got rid of IE7 support. These two things will make this work on IE8:

- IE8 is very picky about valid HTML: you need to close the form tag
- comment out "elm.unbind('input').unbind('keydown').unbind('change');"

My version of this:

```
.directive('checkEmailOnBlur', function($timeout){
    var EMAIL_REGX = /^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/;
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
            if (attr.type === 'radio' || attr.type === 'checkbox') return;

            elm.bind('blur', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    if (EMAIL_REGX.test(elm.val())) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('emails', true);
                    } else {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('emails', false);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
});

<form name="myForm">
            <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: myForm.mail.$invalid}">
                <label>mail</label>
                <input type="text" name="mail" ng-model="user.mail" check-email-on-blur />
                <span ng-show="myForm.mail.$error.emails" class="help-inline">Invalid email</span>
            </div>
        </form>
```